# Error calling the azure function endpoint from azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have linked azure function in data factory pipeline which writes the text file to blob storage 
The azure function works fine when executed independently and writes the file to blob storage
But i am facing below mentioned error when i run the azure function from data factory

```
{
    "errorCode": "3600",
    "message": "Error calling the endpoint.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Azure Function1"
}
```

I have configured the azure fucntion to access the blob with blobendpoint and  shared access signature as mentioned below

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XYZ;AccountKey=XYZ;BlobEndpoint=ABC;SharedAccessSignature=AAA"
```

Please let me know if i need to make some additional properties changes in blob storage to access azure function successfully  from data factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the trigger in your azure function? http trigger?
Also how is your azure function protected? 
if protected using AAD you need Bearer token.
if you are using keys you need x-function key.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#authorization-keys

Here is a video from channel9 that might help:

Run Azure Functions from Azure Data Factory pipelines

https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Run-Azure-Functions-from-Azure-Data-Factory-pipelines

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,Yes azure function is having input http trigger and output blob trigger

Comment: Azure Function linked service
The return type of the Azure function has to be a valid JObject. (Keep in mind that JArray is not a JObject.) Any return type other than JObject fails and raises the generic user error Error calling endpoint. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity

Comment: I am getting same error 
{
"errorCode": "3600",
"message": "Error calling the endpoint.",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "Azure FunctionFinalTest"
}

It works fine in one account after returning valid JObject.
But if i run the same data factory azure function with different account it throws same generic error .

Comment: try with a different pipeline, account to isolate the probleme maybe a network issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Function Activity in the ADF pipeline expects the Azure Function to return a JSON object instead of an HttpResponseMessage.
Here is how we solved it:
https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2019/01/introducing-azure-function-activity-to.html