# Calling Azure Function from ADF with Route Path Implementation Fails

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to call an Azure Function from ADF. Azure Function has Route implemented as shown below.

```
[FunctionName("UpdateStatus_V1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "V1/UpdateStatus")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

Also the host file has a routePrefix in Azure Function

```
"http": {
  "routePrefix": "DeltaAPI"
}
```

URI on the Function APP appears as below.

https://functionAPP.azurewebsites.net/DeltaAPI/V1/UpdateStatus?code=secret

When i try to invoke this function from Azure Data Factory using a Function Activity - I keep getting this error

```
{ 
   "errorCode":"3608",
   "message":"Call to provided Azure function '' failed with status-'NotFound' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.",
   "failureType":"UserError",
   "target":"Azure Function1"
}
```

I have followed the recommendation as per document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity#routing-and-queries and the adf pipeline code is given below:

```
{
  "name": "FunctionTest",
  "properties": {
    "activities": [
      {
        "name": "Azure Function1",
        "type": "AzureFunctionActivity",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "policy": {
          "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
          "retry": 0,
          "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
          "secureOutput": false,
          "secureInput": false
        },
        "userProperties": [],
        "typeProperties": {
          "functionName": "V1/UpdateStatus",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          "body": {
            "value": "@json( '{\n \"transactionid\": \"5d283e11e62943ceb2e6e0bb5fe4898f\",\n \"status\": \"Completed\",\n \"Description\": \"\"\n }')",
            "type": "Expression"
          }
        },
        "linkedServiceName": {
          "referenceName": "AzureFunction",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        }
      }
    ],
    "annotations": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Function Activity in the ADF pipeline expects the Azure Function to return a JSON object instead of an HttpResponseMessage. Here is how you can solve it: https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2019/01/introducing-azure-function-activity-to.html

Ref - [Error calling the azure function endpoint from azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54441426/error-calling-the-azure-function-endpoint-from-azure-data-factory)

Comment: The response from azure function is coming back in json as expected. If i use the web activity this works fine. ADF is not able to get to the function with version implemented. ADF is not able to recognize or reach the function as per the error message.