# GET method for an Azure function within Azure Data Factory fails

Tags: json, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I am trying to invoke an  `HTTP` triggered `Azure function` built on with a `GET` request. I setup the linked service as per the recommended steps and the function itself works with a query string through POSTMAN or internet browser, but fails when I try to invoke through Data factory.

```
{
    "errorCode": "3608",
    "message": "Call to provided Azure function '' failed with status-'NotFound' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - NotFound.'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Azure Function1",
    "details": []
}
```

I came across another stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497119/4212430 where there was a mention of a `JSON` response for ADF.

I have since changed my python code to provide an `HTTP` response as a `JSON` object as below

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    statename = req.params.get('statename')
    if not statename:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            statename = req_body.get('statename')

    if statename:
        initiate_main(statename)
        host.close()
        function_message = {"Response":"Successfully trasnferred BOM files"}
        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(function_message),
            mimetype="application/json", 
            status_code=200)
    else:
        function_message = {"Response":"Error in transferring files"}
        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(function_message), 
            mimetype="application/json", 
            status_code=400)
```

But that hasn't helped either.

Comment: Is this relevant https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/40503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the wrong URI with an `api` added at the end while I should have just been giving the plain function name